# Preventing user from login after registration in asp.net register control

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.Net's Create User Wizard Control.

I want that once the user is created, that user should not be logged in. Users cannot register themselves, only a host user can add them.

What happens is, once the user is registered, the host account is logged out and the user whose account is created, is being logged in.

So I want the new user to not be logged in once they are created.

I tried the properties below of the Create User Wizard Control

- Added `DisableCreatedUser="True"` Property so that the user is disabled after registration
- `LoginCreatedUser="False"`

This works, user is not directly logged in after registration, but if page is refreshed, the user gets logged in and host is logged out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your current code and try removing this. It should stop the user from logging in when you refresh the page.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(createUserWizard1.UserName, False);
```

Comment: Seems like commenting the above line works, atleast it worked in my case.

Comment: Yes sorry, should be removing that line.